# Find a individual google sheet position referenced as a number

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, position, spreadsheet

Part of a large script creates a copy of a hidden sheet and then moves it to position 3 from the left since i have it's sister sheet moved to position 2 already.

However, i later realized that the script can be run from a number of sheet positions so i need to obtain the current location of the active sheet.

(eg. (1) Sheet is in position 1, runs script and sister sheet copy moves to 3 vs. (2) sheet is in position 5, runs script & sister sheet copy moves to 3rd position --- not next to it on the right side).

How do i find a sheet's position? 
because right now i'm just asking the sheet to always be in position 3 when created anew.

```
ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(3);
```

I saw this thread, but i couldn't make heads or tails of it.
[Duplicate worksheet with copy placed next to original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56084099/duplicate-worksheet-with-copy-placed-next-to-original)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can find your sheet index with this script:

```
function FindSheetIndex() {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('SheetB');

  //Here the index of SheetB
  var mySheetIdx=sheet.getIndex();
  //if you want to activate your sheet by mySheetIndex
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[mySheetIdx-1]);
  return mySheetIdx;
}
```